# How to generate a GARCH series contaminated with outliers

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, garch

How can I simulate a GARCH series that is contaminated with both additive and innovative outliers?  My goal is compare different robust estimators. I am using R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example for GARCH(1,1) (the R code should be self-explanatory):

```
T=500
y=sigma.sq=rep(NA,T+1)
set.seed(1); innov=rnorm(T+1)
omega=0.05; alpha=0.1; beta=0.85
sigma.sq[1]=1/(alpha+beta)

# Below you specify the additive and multiplicative outliers
add.out=rep(0,T+1); add.out[100]=10; add.out[300]=20
mul.out=rep(1,T+1); mul.out[200]=10; add.out[400]=20

# Generate a GARCH(1,1) process with both additive and multiplicative outliers
for(t in 2:(T+1)){
 sigma.sq[t]=(omega+alpha*(sigma.sq[t-1]*innov[t-1]^2)+beta*sigma.sq[t-1]+add.out[t])*mul.out[t]
 y[t]=innov[t]*sqrt(sigma.sq[t])
}
sigma.sq=sigma.sq[-1]
y=y[-1]

# Plot the process and its conditional standard deviations
ylim=range( c( y,sqrt(sigma.sq) ) )
plot(y,type="l",ylim=ylim)
lines(sqrt(sigma.sq),col="red")
```

[image]

Here the outliers affect the conditional variance equation. You can easily change the code so that the outliers affect the realized values directly: replace

```
 sigma.sq[t]=(omega+(sigma.sq[t-1]*alpha*innov[t-1]^2)+beta*sigma.sq[t-1]+add.out[t])*mul.out[t]
 y[t]=innov[t]*sqrt(sigma.sq[t])
```

with

```
 sigma.sq[t]=omega+(sigma.sq[t-1]*alpha*innov[t-1]^2)+beta*sigma.sq[t-1]
 y[t]=(innov[t]*sqrt(sigma.sq[t])+add.out[t])*mul.out[t]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot , but i am wondering is the multiplicative outliers the same as innovative outliers in garch model

Comment: @mona I suppose it depends on how you define things, but I do not see why they should be the same. My example code shows both types of outliers. You can play with the code, e.g. change the size or the locations of the outliers, add more of them or remove the existing ones. That way you might get a better feel for what effects the outliers have.

Comment: @RichardHardy Hi Richard, I wonder if the code you used to generate the conditional variances are correct; more specifically: `sigma.sq[t] = omega + alpha * innov[t-1] ^ 2 + beta * sigma.sq[t-1]` (I omitted the terms for the outliers). Shouldn't the white noise `innov[t-1]` be replaced by the actual residual at `t-1` (which is dependent on `sigma.sq[t-1]`)?

Comment: @XiuboZhang, you are right, I will have to fix it.

Comment: @RichardHardy I was going through [this](http://www.econ.nthu.edu.tw/bin/downloadfile.php?file=WVhSMFlXTm9MemMyTDNCMFlWOHlNamczTVY4eU5UQTNPRGhmTWpJd05qVXVjR1Jt&fname=HDJHWTCHJDSTDGRP1501RL04IHVTCD51GHRPEHDD35JHTWCHSXFD15CHEDIHWX50A5VTCDPKJDA5DD40STSTKOVX) slide deck; on page 11, the author showed an alternative specification for GARCH involving a white noise series, which suggests a easy correction to the original code: `sigma.sq[t] = omega + alpha * sigma.sq[t-1] * innov[t-1] ^ 2 + beta * sigma.sq[t-1]`

Comment: @XiuboZhang, thank you very much. I edited fast, I hope I got it right this time. The mistake was a stupid one.